# Playwright console debugging in Node

Tags: node.js, playwright

Is it possible to debug playwright on the fly?
In python, you just stop the console and can play around with the values. But in Node, all the methods return a pending promise. It's very annoying to need to rerun each test to check for values. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you explain with an small code example with what exactly annoys you in JS?

Answer (score 1):

Note: This is an general answer in lack of specific information in the question but will be helpful for any general new playwright user.

### Debugging Playwright Tests

First , in the VS code editor you'll need to install the extension called 'Playwright Test for VSCode'.

For each point below to see further details , please follow the respective link to the Playwright Docs.

#### [Use VS Code debugger](https://playwright.dev/docs/debug#vs-code-debugger)

With the VS Code extension you can debug your tests right in VS Code, see error messages, set breakpoints and step through your tests.

##### [Error Messages](https://playwright.dev/docs/debug#error-messages)

If your test fails VS Code will show you error messages right in the editor showing what was expected, what was received as well as a complete call log.

##### [Live Debugging](https://playwright.dev/docs/debug#live-debugging)

You can debug your test live in VS Code. After running a test with the Show Browser option checked, click on any of the locators in VS Code and it will be highlighted in the Browser window. Playwright will also show you if there are multiple matches.

You can also edit the locators in VS Code and Playwright will show you the changes live in the browser window.

##### [Playwright Inspector](https://playwright.dev/docs/debug#playwright-inspector)

The Playwright Inspector is a GUI tool to help you debug your Playwright tests. It allows you to step through your tests, live edit locators, pick locators and see actionability logs.

Answer (score 1):

In VS code you'll need to install a plugin called `Playwright Test for VSCode`.

In WebStorm you may use `Maestro` plugin.  It's payed however it has a month or so of trial to try. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18100-maestro

in latest version of Playwright they simplified logging. so now for simple checks you can use `console.log()` right away.
https://playwright.dev/docs/release-notes